# How can I shorten the following Ruby code?

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes, all with the same keys, all with a key of `id`. I need a comma delimited string of ids.

```
arr_widgets = []
widgets.each do |widget|
  arr_widgets.push(widget['id'])
end

str_widgets = arr_widgets.join(',')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
str_widgets = widgets.map { |w| w['id'] }.join(',')
```

Comment: This is a common pattern that's worth learning. `x = []; y.each { |v| ... x << f(y) }; x` reduces to this `map`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create an intermediate array.

```
widgets = [
  {"id"=>"dec"}, {"id"=>21}, {"id"=>2020}, {"id"=>"was"},
  {"id"=>"the"}, {"id"=>"shortest"}, {"id"=>"day"}, {"id"=>"of"},
  {"id"=>"the"}, {"id"=>"longest"}, {"id"=>"year"}
]
```

Note that two values are integers.

```
s = widgets.each_with_object(String.new) do |widget, s|
  s << ',' unless s.empty?
  s << widget["id"].to_s
end

puts s
  #=> "dec,21,2020,was,the,shortest,day,of,the,longest,year"
```

Comment: Does not work with `frozen_string_literal: true` (would need to change `str <<` to `str +=`). Does not work with `id` values that are not strings.

Comment: @anothermh, point #2 is a good one (have fixed). I don't follow #1 as the value of the block variable `str` is not frozen. Perhaps you could give an example. I don't believe `str +=` would work. I think you'd need `str.replace(str +...)` (or use `reduce`).

Comment: Make a new file `foo.rb`. Add `# frozen_string_literal: true` as the first line, then add both your blocks of code, then run `ruby foo.rb`: `foo.rb:11:in 'block in <main>': can't modify frozen String: "" (FrozenError)`. Change `<<` to `+=` and it does not produce an error.

Comment: @anothermh or simply substitute `''` with `String.new` that being said the magic comment is completely optional at the moment (even as of 3.0.0) so if someone were to enact its usage they should understand what corrective action should be taken.

Comment: @anothermh and smnky, I see the problem and will address it when my dog and I return from our walk through Beacon Hill Park. (The pragma comment `#frozen_string_literal: true` is new to me.)

Comment: @engineersmnky There are plenty of people working in existing projects that don't know what the pragma means or is for, who can't replicate the issue in IRB because the strings aren't frozen, who might be left scratching their heads. It's an unfortunate thing that frozen strings were pushed so hard only to be left behind for Ruby3, leaving a fragmented base.

Comment: @anothermh, my revision now works when the pragma comment `# frozen_string_literal: true` is at the beginning of the file.

Comment: @engineersmnky, thank you for the suggestion to use `String.new`.

Comment: @anothermh while I can agree the proposed paradigm shift has built camps, the pragma is still wholly optional and if one (or a team) opts in this should be communicated clearly. Even the [documentation](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/String.html#method-i-3C-3C) is clear that `'foo' << 'bar'` is perfectly valid. Thus the use of `String.new` or even `+=` would be considered non-idiomatic in my opinion.

Comment: I agree that it's valid if mutable but not all objects are. `<<` is fine if you want to mutate one object in place but that doesn't work in a world with frozen objects. `+=` is the idiomatic solution because it works in all circumstances by generating new objects rather than mutating existing objects. A solution that works sometimes but not others depending on what magic comments you're using or version of Ruby you're using is not, to me, the idiomatic one, even if it was more common in the past.

Comment: @anothermh, I don't know what you mean by "in a world of frozen objects". Are you referring to a situation where one cannot create a string, literal or not, that is not frozen? If so, how would that be done? If I were to write `widgets.each_with_object('') do |widget, s| s +=...` (or `...with_object(String.new)...`) the initialized object (an empty string) would be returned as `s += ...` does not alter that object. To use `s += ...` one would have to write `s = ''; widgets.each do |widget| s +=...`. Alternatively, one could write `widgets.reduce('') do |s, widget| s + ...`.

Comment: @engineersmnky, having an idea of how your mind works I'm surprised you didn't suggest `...each_with_object('' + '')..`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland there are so many better bastardizations to create an "unfrozen" string from a literal which is why this conversation seems a bit pedantic `''.ljust(0)` (and freinds `rjust`,`slice`, etc.),`''.dump.undump`, but I think I would most likely prefer `+''`